# How to add a member to the list in a mailchimp api using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am doing "Angela Yu" bootcamp for Web Dev, where you make a web app to add a member to you maillist. When the user enters their the details to the Info Page and click submit, the user should be added to the mail list using mailchimp api. I have gone through documentation, it looks like they updated it, still I have run the code according to the documentation, but I am getting 400 statusCode. Could any please tell me how to write the code in this case? I am ahing my HTML, CSS and Javascript pages

```
    const express = require("express");
    const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    const request = require('request');
    const https = require("https");
    const mailchimp = require("@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing");

    const app = express();

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
      extended: true
    }));
    app.use(express.static("public"));

    mailchimp.setConfig({
      apiKey: "7a6374510cc1647147c788b55eb3db8b-us21",
      server: "us21",
    });

    app.get("/", function(req, res) {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html");
    });

    app.post("/", function(req, res) {
      const listId = "df58b4dffb";
      const subscribingUser = {
        firstName: req.body.fName,
        lastName: req.body.lName,
        email: req.body.email
      };

      async function run() {
        const response = await mailchimp.lists.addListMember(listId, {
          email_address: subscribingUser.email,
          status: "subscribed",
          merge_fields: {
            FNAME: subscribingUser.firstName,
            LNAME: subscribingUser.lastName
          }
        });

        console.log(
          `Successfully added contact as an audience member. The contact's id is ${
          response.id
        }.`
        );
      }

      run();
    });
```

I have tried to run a code according to the documentation but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require('express');
const https = require('https');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mailchimp = require("@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing");
const listId = "your ID";
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html")
    })

    app.post('/',(req, res) => {
        var fname =req.body.firstName;
        var lname =req.body.lastName;
        var mail = req.body.email;
       
        console.log(fname)
        console.log(lname)
        console.log(mail)

        mailchimp.setConfig({
          apiKey: "your key",
          server: "your server address"
        });
        
        const subscribingUser = {
            firstName:fname,
            lastName: lname,
            email: mail
          };
        async function run() {
          const response = await mailchimp.lists.addListMember(listId,{
            email_address: subscribingUser.email,
            status: "subscribed",
            merge_fields: {
              FNAME: subscribingUser.firstName,
              LNAME: subscribingUser.lastName,
              PHONE: '998866554433',
            }
            
          });
         
        console.log(
            `Successfully created an audience. The audience id is 
          ${response.id}.`
          );
          console.log(response);
        }
       
        run();
       
    });

    app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("server started at port "+port);
})
```

Comment: Hello, please provide some details for your answer - what you changed. why you changed it, etc.